# Closed Loop Control Error

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, linear-control

I'm trying to investigate the evolution of the error function in a closed loop.

What I am basically trying to find is a way to understand, checking only the error, if the control loop is working well.

My idea is that if the error is in his bounds then everything is fine and since these bounds decrease in amplitude as time goes by, in the end, I should be able to find out if the loop "goes crazy"

From what I understood:

1) The majority (>60%) of the closed loops used in the world are linear

2) In the linear controls error upper and lower bounds can be described using a mathematical functions that I can compute using the loop parameters

Are these statements correct? 
And, if so, what can I use in non linear systems?

Thank you,
:)

Comment: 1.) A closed loop consists usually of a controller and a plant. Even if the controller is linear, in practice, all plants are nonlinear (to some degree). So, strictly speaking, this claim is wrong. 2.) Depends, what do you mean with "the error is in his bounds"?

Comment: Hello SampleTime! 
first of all thanks for your help! Unfortunately I don't know much about this world so I may be imprecise :)

I am mainly interested in the controller, not in the plants: what I was thinking as bounds are basically the blue lines here (https://imgur.com/a/3wp36FP).

Ideally I know all the parameters of the controller and I can read the setpoint and the input (so i can compute the error). 
These bounds should be computable starting from the controller parameters right?